# Sitecore 8 PowerShell Get-User Custom Properties

Tags: powershell, sitecore, sitecore8

I need to return either a) a list of users with specific value in a profile field OR b) return the entirety of the users with the value of the profile field displayed in the results.

Currently, I am running the following but it has been running for an hour even though I only have one test user with this field set to this value.

```
Get-User -Filter * | Where-Object {Profile.GetCustomProperties("Subscribed") -eq "yup"}
```

Comment: I don't have Sitecore to verify this, but it looks like you are trying to filter on the objects you are retrieving from the `Get-User` cmdlet. So you'll need to use `$_` or `$psitem`. e.g. `Get-User -Filter * | Where-Object {$_.Profile.GetCustomProperties("Subscribed") -eq "yup"}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Sitecore to verify this, but it looks like you are trying to filter on the objects you are retrieving from the `Get-User` cmdlet. So you'll need to use `$_` or `$psitem`. Something like:

```
Get-User -Filter * | Where-Object {$_.Profile.GetCustomProperties("Subscribed") -eq "yup"}`
```

I can't comment on the length this will take, but it looks like you pull every user with `Get-User` then run the `GetCustomProperties()` method on each one, so depending on how many users that may take a while.